# Need PHP preg_replace for AMP Instagram, Twitter Embed

Tags: php, preg-replace, amp-html

I am working on custom AMP for Wordpress and don't want to use any library for some reasons.

I want to convert the normal EMBED URL to AMP Url with preg_replace, i did it for youtube and its working fine here is an example.

```
/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i
```

with

```
<amp-youtube width="480" height="270" layout=responsive data-videoid="$1"></amp-youtube>
```

Now i need to convert these two

https://www.instagram.com/p/BmUm-8DH2Qq/?hl=en&taken-by=sonamkapoor

Need this ID **BmUm-8DH2Qq** so i can make the AMP Code like this

```
<amp-instagram class="no-bottom" data-shortcode="BmUm-8DH2Qq<" width="1" height="1" layout="responsive"></amp-instagram>
```

https://twitter.com/ANI/status/1040050654172131328

And Need this ID **1040050654172131328** to make the AMP Code

```
<amp-twitter class="no-bottom" width="390" height="330" layout="responsive" data-tweetid="1040050654172131328" data-cards="hidden"></amp-twitter>
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? What doesn't work with your code?

Comment: I can't make the preg_replace code to extract the Twitter and Instagram IDs to use  in my AMP.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regex, you could use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with `PHP_URL_PATH` as the component and then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with a forward slash `/` as the delimiter.

For example:

```
$path = parse_url("https://www.instagram.com/p/BmUm-8DH2Qq/?hl=en&taken-by=sonamkapoor", PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $path);
echo $parts[2]; // BmUm-8DH2Qq
echo '<amp-instagram class="no-bottom" data-shortcode="' . $parts[2] . '" width="1" height="1" layout="responsive"></amp-instagram>';

$path2 = parse_url("https://twitter.com/ANI/status/1040050654172131328", PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts2 = explode('/', $path2);
echo $parts2[3]; // 1040050654172131328
echo '<amp-twitter class="no-bottom" width="390" height="330" layout="responsive" data-tweetid="' . $parts2[3] . '" data-cards="hidden"></amp-twitter>';
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ficKl)

Comment: But the issue is i am getting the links from <?php get_the_content(); ?>

Comment: Is it an option the use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to get the links?